# How to filter with Firebase DataSnapshot firebase and with two parameters in Flutter Dart

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, flutter, dart

I'v ben struggled with this simple/multiple query from firebase & dart.

I need filter this entities 'meals' by creatorId and by %text%

```
.orderByChild('title')
.orderByChild('creatorId')
```

I apreciate any help!

```
await DBRef.reference()
    .child('meals')
    .orderByChild('title')
    .startAt(text)
    .orderByChild('creatorId')
    .equalTo(userId)
    .once()
    .then((DataSnapshot snapshotResult) {
  snapshot = snapshotResult;

  if (snapshot == null || snapshot.value==null ) return;
  map = snapshot.value;
  print(map.values.toList().toString());
  // print( 'map ' + map.toString());
});
```

I'm getting this error when put this two orderByChild

```
'!_parameters.containsKey('orderBy')': is not true.
```

So, how I suppose to filter with two params?

Comment: Firebase Database queries can only order/filter on a single property. In many cases it is possible to combine the values you want to filter on into a single (synthetic) property. For an example of this and other approaches, see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase

Comment: @exequielc if the answer helped you please mark it as correct and upvote it so others know that it is useful, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In firebase real time database you cannot do this filter. You can only use one `orderByChild()` and not multiple. To fix this you can change your database to the following for example:

```
random id
     meals
       random id
             title : "chicken"
             creatorId : "1234"
             title_creator : "chicken_1234"
```

```
await DBRef.reference()
    .child('meals')
    .orderByChild('title_creator')
    .equalTo("chicken_1234")
    .once()
```